# What adjective describes following a clockwise direction?

Tags: single-word-requests

Or anti-clockwise direction. I want to contrast the difference between the order in which the Japanese say the cardinal directions, compared to the order Western countries say them. They say 'east west south north'. Personally, I think of this mode of thought as dimensional. But our mode of thought involves starting from a fixed point (north) and then listing the directions going in a clockwise direction. Is there an adjective which describes this?

Comment: Dextral and Sinistral.

Comment: @JoeDark What do you understand by Dextral and Sinistral?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextrorotation_and_levorotation

Comment: Our mode of thought? Not everyone who speaks English thinks the same way as you. For me it's North South East West.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I believe the Japanese took over this order from the Chinese, and that the order is in fact the exact same as ours: top, bottom, right, left. Old Chinese maps had East at the top, not North. Similarly, where we would say a road runs east-west (right-left) or north-south (top-bottom), the Chinese and Japanese would say that it runs east-west (top-bottom) or south-north (right-left). And of course, @andy256’s point stands: I have personally never heard anyone say “north east south west” in _any_ language.

Comment: Okay, maybe my hypothesis was wrong (although you really haven't heard of Never Eat Shredded Wheat, Janus? That's ubiquitous afaik where I live, anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

Synonyms for *clockwise* and *anti-clockwise (counter-clockwise* to us Americans) include *deasil* and *widdershins* respectively, which have Celtic and ritual roots and associations.

Comment: I'm not looking for a synonym of clockwise; clockwise is an adverb, whereas I'm looking for an adjective.

Comment: @LeoKing Look no further than your own headline and first line then, where you have used *clockwise* and *anti-clockwise* (correctly) as adjectives.

Answer (score 2):

> [Dextrorotary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Dextrorotary) **adj**., rotating to the right

Comment: And *levoratory* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/levorotatory

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we refer to compass points in more of a cross-wise configuration - otherwise it would sound like you were saying Northeast and Southwest. Maybe, "Oppositionally designated , beginning north to south, then east to west."